# Laravel 4: Decode Json in email view

Tags: json, laravel, laravel-4

I have an email app built in laravel 4. My users need the ability to add multiple promotions to their email signature line, but I am completely stuck trying to get the data into the email view.

Specifically, the problem I'm running into is that I am trying to send an array, $mData, to my mail view which includes an array of json encoded objects.

I might have my terminology wrong, so here is an example:

```
$mData['subject'] = 'this is a subject line';
$mData['promotion'] = [[{"id":1,"user_id":2,"path":"\/uploads\/attachments\/XDIzaf9lfcHg.jpg"},{"id":2,"user_id":2,"path":"\/uploads\/attachments\/XDIzaf9lfcHg.jpg"}]]
```

I then need to iterate through $mData['promotion'] in the email to display images inline.  I haven't been able to figure out how to format $mData['promotion'] so that I can iterate through it.

Here is my mail constructor:

```
public function emailConstructor($subject, $body)
{
    $userId = $this->user->id;
    $eloquentUser = User::find($userId);
    $mData['from'] = $this->user->email;
    $mData['fromName']= $this->user->first_name. " ". $this->user->last_name;
    $mData['subject'] = $subject;

    $promotionCount = $this->emailPromotionCount($userId);

        if(count($promotionCount) >= 1){
            $mData['promotion'] = $promotionCount;
        }

    return $mData;
} 

public function emailPromotionCount($userId)
 {
  $count = SignaturePromotion::where('user_id', '=', $userId)->get();

  $promotionCount =  json_encode(array($count));

    return $promotionCount;

 }
```

My mailer function is pretty standard:

```
public function emailTo($view, $mData)
{
    Mail::send($view, $mData, function($message) use ($mData)
    {
      $message->from($mData['from'], $mData['fromName']);
      $message->to($mData['email'], $mData['name'])->subject($mData['subject']);
      $message->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-MC-Metadata', $mData['meta']);
        if(array_key_exists('path', $mData)){
            $message->attach($mData['path'], array('as' => $mData['display']));
        }
    });
}
```

I've tried to decode the JSON several ways.  This is a snippet from my email blade file:

```
<div>
  @if($promotion)
   @foreach(json_decode($promotion) as $promo)
     {{$promo->path}}
   @endforeach
  @endif
```

any idea how to properly format $mData['promotion'] so I can loop through it in the email view?

**EDIT - for answer**

The problem was how I was encoding my json:

```
$count = SignaturePromotion::where('user_id', '=', $userId)->get();

  $promotionCount =  json_encode(array($count));
```

should be

```
$count = SignaturePromotion::where('user_id', '=', $userId)->get()->toJson();
```

No need for $promotionCount =  json_encode(array($count));

Comment: remove one "[" from left side[[{"id":1 and "]" from right side, or use @foreach(json_decode($promotion) as $promo)
@foreach($promo as $reallyNeededArray)

Comment: and you should set quotes to, because JSON is a text.
$mData['promotion'] = '[[{"id":1,"user_id":2,"path":"\/uploads\/attachments\/XDIzaf9lfcHg.jpg"},{"id":2,"user_id":2,"path":"\/uploads\/attachments\/XDIzaf9lfcHg.jpg"}]]';

Comment: Hey, thanks @KoIIIeY - rookie mistake... I appreciate it.